# PHP Find the first scientificly significant 'non zero' digits of an floating number

Tags: php, math, floating-point

In this question, I am using the word significant in a scientific context

I want to retrieve the first n digits from the left of a floating number. The function should take in:

- the $number which is the floating point number.
- The $n which is the amount of numbers to retrieve.

Here are some example inputs and outputs that I would like the function to return:

- When $number= 5678 and $n=2 then  -> result should be:  56
- When $number= -69869 and $n=4 then -> result should be: 6986
- When $number= 0.00676 and $n=2 then -> result should be: 67
- When $number= -0.0000048 and $n= 3 then ->result should be: 480

I tried some math functions to achieve this, and got pretty far, but the last one gives problems in

```
$result = (int)(abs($number)/pow(10,(int)(log10(abs($number)))-$n));
```

It returns 479 as answer. This is because I am working with floating points, and I don’t know a way around this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with strings. Is this an option?

```
$result = (int)str_pad(substr((int)str_replace('.','',preg_replace('/E‌​(.*)/','',abs($numbe‌​r))),0,$n),$n,'0',ST‌​R_PAD_RIGHT);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but no. It wil return 0 in the last example. Because the substr(str_replace('.','',abs($number)),0,$n); wil return 48E. And the E wil cause the error.

Comment: It's working for me with all tested PHP versions. Which version are you using? Is it no option in general or just because of this problem?

Comment: It should be `substr((int)str_replace('.','',abs($number))` not `substr(str_replace('.','',abs($number))`. In my answer it's correct!

Comment: I have the latest xampp running, so that is PHP 5.6.30. But i don't think that is the problem. The E is generated in the string when only 2 significant numbers ar present and more than 7 or 8 zero's in front of them (as desimal.) becouse the entire string wil be somthing like 48E-8 where the E stands for 10 to the power -8

Comment: The `(int)`cast will remove the E-stuff

Comment: Not in my case, and a don't know why. But the cast wil return 0. because it cant interpret the E. substr((int)str_replace('.','',abs($number)),0,$n) wil return 0. and str_replace('.','',abs($number)) wil return 48E-6

Comment: Try it like this `$result = (int)str_pad(substr((int)str_replace('.','',preg_replace('/E(.*)/','',abs($number))),0,$n),$n,'0',STR_PAD_RIGHT);` Sorry I'm too bad at math, I can only try it with strings :)